# How to click a select menu with label name using cypress?

Tags: cypress

i want to click a select menu with its label name using cypress.

what i am trying to do?

I have two select menus with labels label1 and label2 and i want to click the select menu with label "label2".

below is the code,

```
<div class="Box">
    <label for="label1">label1</label>
    <div class="Select">
        <div class="Select_control">
        </div>
        <div class="Select_indicators">
            <button>
                <svg>
                    <title>down</title>
                </svg>
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="Box">
    <label for="label2">label2</label>
    <div class="Select">
        <div class="Select_control">
        </div>
        <div class="Select_indicators">
            <button>
                <svg>
                    <title>down</title>
                </svg>
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have tried to use

```
cy.get('.Select__indicators')
   .clickIconButtonByName('down');
```

but this clicks the button for first select menu that is for "label1"

I want it to select for "label2". how can i do it. could someone help me with this. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```js
cy.contains('label2')
  .parent()
  .within(() => {
    cy.get('.Select__indicators').clickIconButtonByName('down')
  })
```

First find the `label2` element with text. Then using `parent()` go to the **box** parent element. Then using `within` scope the next query into the second box which has label2.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have several elements with the class 'Select_indicators' it will find both your divs with that name.

I recommend that you instead give each of those divs a unique id

```
<div id="my_first_select" class="Select_indicators">
...
<div id="my_second_select" class="Select_indicators">
...
```

Then you can instead search for the specific one you want to test

```
cy.get('#my_second_select').clickIconButtonByName('down');
```

Answer (score 0):

The best practice in cypress is we test on the web that you can control so that you can add specific attribute to the DOM

There are several option you can add

1. add an id for specific selector
2. add an data-* attribute (best practice mentioned by cypress here https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/best-practices#Selecting-Elements)

with specific id or data-* you can easily select the element with `cy.get()`.

```html
<div id="firstSelect" class="Select_indicators">
<div class="Select_indicators" data-id="firstSelect">
```

```js
cy.get('#firstSelect').click()
cy.get('[data-id=firstSelect]').click()
```

Or if it is not possible to add id or data-* attribute you still can select element using combination of `cy.contains()` and cypress traversal command listed here : https://example.cypress.io/commands/traversal.

But when doing test this way there is a chance that the test became flaky since the UI can be changed on the development process.